# I can not get into the event when I click the dynamically created button

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, events, foreach

I am trying to make the program, with the click of the button, enter the event but I can't, can someone help me?

The "foreach" is working but it does not enter and I don't know why.

when the button is clicked it doesn't start the event but when it's clicked twice all buttons desapear

```
foreach (var Cat in db.Categorias) {
    var id_Categoria = db.Categorias.Where(x => x.IdCategoria.Equals(Cat.IdCategoria)).FirstOrDefault();
    if (id_Categoria != null && Cat.IdCategoria.Equals(Cat.IdCategoria)) {
        UpdatePanel UP_btn_Cat = new UpdatePanel();
        UP_btn_Cat.ID = "UP_btn_Cat_" + Cat.IdCategoria.ToString();
        UP_btn_Cat.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
        Plh_cat.Controls.Add(UP_btn_Cat);

        Button btn_cat = new Button();
        btn_cat.Text = Cat.NomeCategoria;
        btn_cat.ID = "btn_cat_" + Cat.IdCategoria.ToString();
        btn_cat.Click += new EventHandler(button_Click);
        UP_btn_Cat.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(btn_cat);

        AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
        trigger.ControlID = btn_cat.ID;
        trigger.EventName = "button_Click";
        UP_btn_Cat.Triggers.Add(trigger);

        Plh_email.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<div style='clear: both'></div>"));
    }
}

protected void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Button btn_cat = (Button)sender;

    PlaceHolder plh_msg_cat = new PlaceHolder();
    plh_msg_cat.ID = "plh_msg_cat";

    UpdatePanel UP_mgs_Cat = new UpdatePanel();
    UP_mgs_Cat.ID = "UP_mgs_Cat";
    UP_mgs_Cat.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
    div_msgs.Controls.Add(UP_mgs_Cat);

    AsyncPostBackTrigger trigger = new AsyncPostBackTrigger();
    trigger.ControlID = btn_cat.ID;
    trigger.EventName = "Click";
    UP_mgs_Cat.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    var id = btn_cat.ID;
    Plh_cat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<p class='p_cliente'>123" + id + "</p>"));
}
```

Comment: is your code working ? aren't you getting error in the foor loop ?

Comment: @WaleedNaveed my code works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how everything is created but I would suggest you read up on the [Page Life Cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). It states that all controls must be created during the PreInit event. Use the Init to initialize control properties.

If the controls are created only once during !IsPostBack or in the wrong event, then the Click event of the button will not fire.

Comment: the button is working fine but the event doesn't start.

Comment: You help me, please?